# Node app fails with SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Using Babel and Webpack to build a React application.

During the build process, it fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

Answer (score 2):

Babel 6 introduced a change to no longer transpile ES2015 by default. See more detail here: https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0

To fix this, edit your **package.json** or **.babelrc** file to include `{ "presets": ["es2015"] }`

Here's an example of the section of my package.json file with the fix:

```
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-middleware": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "node5",
      "stage-0",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "rewire"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
```

Comment: `stage-0` <- this is crazy. I highly recommend to not use it.

Comment: Just because something does odd things - does not mean you should too :-) PS: using starter kits is even a bigger evil than using `stage-0`

Comment: yeah, it's way too heavy to use as a boilerplate for a real app (IMO) but good for learning.